# How to deal with corrupt /boot/uefi

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Background on new HP Pavillion 15

1. usual procedure:

   a. delete windows partitions, preserving only /boot/uefi partition

   b. make several ext4 partitions including two for OSes

   c. install Linux on first OS partition

   c. done this procedure for 10 years

   d. the laptop worked perfectly this way since delivery
2. after update with synaptic, reboot hung tried several times the scroll looked as expected - daemons started, etc - up to the point where it hung
3. installed 16.04 from DVD on second OS partition no issues reported in install
4. boot after new install and got the blue screen with error `code 0xc0000225`
5. all diagnostics pointed to by the blue screen passed CPU, memory, disk, etc
6. web search suggests the `/boot/uefi` partition is corrupt

Question: Can I reformat the `/boot/uefi` partition or salvage it in
some way?

Comment: How about enabling CSM and just installing in legacy mode?

Comment: HP is not UEFI dual boot friendly. You generally have to do a work around. You can back up /EFI/ubuntu and /EFI/Microsoft and delete the ESP/FAT32 partition and create new FAT32 partition with boot flag to make new ESP. And restore files. But often you can do this if sda1 or change to correct FAT32 partition: `sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1`  If only booting Ubuntu you can rename boot of shimx64.efi to be "Windows Boot Manager" or use fallback/hard drive entry /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is really shim.http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: The UEFI bootloaders are just files in a FAT filesystem.  Copy them to a USB, see if dosfsck has anything to say about the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

A screen shot of the error message you're seeing may be helpful. I Googled it and found several pages, like [this one,](https://itsolutionsblog.net/solution-to-your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired/) which show screen shots that make it look like this may be a Windows error. If so, then it sounds like your installation method left some Windows files intact, which have somehow been activated and are now trying to take control of the computer. (Side note: If you completely delete an OS from an EFI-based computer, be sure to delete its files on the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) to prevent this "zombie OS" syndrome! In your case, completely deleting the ESP and allowing the Ubuntu installer to create a new one would have been appropriate.) If my suspicion is correct, then deleting those Windows files from the ESP should work around this problem.

If the ESP (mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu) is damaged, or if the Windows boot manager has returned, zombie-style, it should be possible to boot the computer by using my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R. Note, however, that you may need to [disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) if it's enabled. Once the computer has booted, you should be able to investigate further, such as:

- Use `dosfsck` to check for filesystem damage on the ESP. (Be sure to unmount it first.)
- Look for leftover Windows files on the ESP. (They normally reside in `/boot/efi/EFI/Windows`, as seen from Ubuntu.)
- Check the boot order with `sudo efibootmgr -v`. Pay attention to the `BootOrder` line; the first item there indicates the boot loader that the computer tries to launch first. If the `Boot####` line corresponding to the first `BootOrder` line is Windows, then this explains the problem. Deleting the Windows files should fix the problem; or you can adjust the boot order with the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`. In extreme cases, you might need to add a new boot entry for Ubuntu. (Sometimes they go missing, either because of EFI bugs or because of accidents with tools like `efibootmgr`.)

In an extreme case, if the ESP is badly damaged, I recommend:

1. Back up what you can from the ESP. A file-level backup (using `cp`, `tar`, `zip`, or similar tools) is fine.
2. Try using `dosfsck` on the ESP.
3. If `dosfsck` doesn't fix the problem, create a fresh FAT filesystem on the ESP by unmounting it and using `mkdosfs` on it.
4. After creating a fresh filesystem, restore the original files and adjusting the `/etc/fstab` file to mount it using its new serial number (`UUID=` item in `/etc/fstab`; learn the new serial number by using `blkid`).
5. If you *still* can't boot, you'll have to (re-)install a boot loader.

   - [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can completely re-install GRUB in a somewhat automated way.
   - Alternatively, if you're successfully booting via rEFInd or some other temporary tool, you can run `sudo grub-install` followed by `sudo update-grub`. This is a bit less thorough than Boot Repair, but is likely to be sufficient; and is less likely to create new problems through overkill.
   - Yet another option is to install rEFInd via its Debian package, PPA, or (if you're using Ubuntu 17.04) `refind` package in Ubuntu. This will bypass GRUB. You'll need to [jump through a few extra hoops](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) to get it working with Secure Boot, though.

Comment: I did the following steps after consulting the answers posted
(all comparatively non-invasive and reversible):

1) mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
2) cd /mnt/sda1
3) tar cvf <otherdir>/sda1-backup.tar *
4) cd
5) umount /dev/sda1
6) dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1  (no complaints)
7) mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
8) efibootmgr -v
   revealed it was trying to boot from EFI/Microsoft/xxx first
9) mkdir /mnt/sda1/EFI/junk ; mv /mnt/sda1/EFI/Microsoft junk
   There was no Windows directory there just HP, Microsoft, and ubuntu
Reboot.  Failed to boot.

Comment: In that case, see my step #5.